The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid req
<div class="form-group">
<label for="landlordId">Landlord</label> <select
                                                class="form-control" id="landlordId" name="landlordId">
                                                <option value="">- Select Landlord -</option>
                                                <option th:each="l : ${landlordsList}"
                                                    th:value="${l.landlordId}" th:text="${l.name}"></option>
</select>
</div>

The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
I got this error when i use this my backend is Spring MVC
I was Cheak all attributes matched with entity class i cannot get any change

You wrote (in your question): The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error. Are you referring to [HTTP] status code 400, i.e. Bad Request ?

yeah, but the form submits correctly and saved when i remove this tag

Change the 'name' give random name and at controller use @RequestParam("name")
<select class="form-control" id="landlordId" name="abcd">
<option value="">- Select Landlord -</option>
<option th:each="l :${landlordsList}" th:text="${l.name}"
th:value="${l.landlordId}"></option>
</select>

@PostMapping("/saveLease")
public String saveLease(Lease lease, @RequestParam("abcd") int abcd) {
    Landlords landlords = landlordsService.FindById(abcd);
    lease.setLandlordId(landlords);
    leaseService.Save(lease);
    return "redirect:/leaseList";
}

